# Java load a jar using through the way like New XXX()?

Tags: java, android, jar, load

I know that usually after loading a jar, we should use it through by calling `loadClass(),getMethod(),invoke()...`
Is there a way use it through `new XXX()`?
I don't know why a jar has be loaded into JVM, it still can't be called through `new XXX()`.

I created two projects in Eclipe, ProjectA,ProjectB.

I exported ProjectB to a jar, and want to use it in ProjectA through `new XXX()`.
I have added ProjectB to the build path of ProjectA, so I can call `new B()` and Eclipse doesn't report any grammar error. But once compiled, ProjectA doesn't include the class of ProjectB.

But when I execute ProjectA, its reports an error:

> 09-23 04:10:46.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.XXXXX

Is there a way to resolve it?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your issue because I don't see why the heck you need the loadClass or whatever else.

If this is related to Android, please,  read in the official documentation https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html on how to handle projects and dependencies.

You also may like Maven or Gradle. Google foor them.